# PHP regular expression in parentheses outside quotes

Tags: php, regex

In `php` I want to replace the `$` in `{{ $here $their '$literal' }}` with `$this->`.
Which means I would like the result `{{ $this->here $this->their '$literal' }}`, but what I get instead is: `{{ $this->here $their '$literal' }}`

this is my code:

```
<?php

    $str = '{{ $here $their "$literal" }}';
    $search = '{{(?:\'[^\']+\'|"[^"]+")(*SKIP)(*F)|\$([0-9a-zA-Z_]++)}}';
    $replace = '$this->$1';

    // result is {{ $hello $this->by "$literal" }}
    $result = preg_replace('/' . $search . '/U', $replace, $str);

?>
```

Does anyone know how to replace multiple occurrences within the {{ }} that are not quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the `{{...}}` substrings within `preg_replace_callback` and then use your `preg_replace` inside the anonynous method with a bit adjusted regex:

```
$str = '{{ $here $their "$literal" }}';
echo preg_replace_callback('~{{.*?}}~s', function($m) {
    return preg_replace('~(?:\'[^\']+\'|"[^"]+")(*SKIP)(*F)|\$\b~', '$this->$0', $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/SKpRaN)

The `'~{{.*?}}~s'` regex will match non-overlapping occurrences of `{{`, any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first `}}`. The regex inside the `preg_replace` is a bit more complex:

- `(?:\'[^\']+\'|"[^"]+")(*SKIP)(*F)` - `'` followed with 1+ chars other than `'` and then `'` (due to `\'[^\']+\'`), or `"` followed with 1+ chars other than `"` and then `"` (due to `"[^"]+"`), and once that substring is matched, it is discarded and the regex engine proceeds to the next match (due to `(*SKIP)(*F)`)
- `|` - or
- `\$\b` - a `$` symbol that is followed with a word character.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is already enclosed between double curly brackets, you only have to write this:

```
$pattern = '~[^"\'$]*+(?:"[^"]*"[^"\'$]*|\'[^\']*\'[^"\'$]*)*+\$\b\K~A';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, 'this->', $str);
```

But if your double curly brackets enclosed part is in a larger text and you don't want to replace other `$var` outside curly brackets, you need this one:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|{{)[^"\'$}]*+(?:"[^"]*"[^"\'$}]*|\'[^\']*\'[^"\'$}]*)*+\$\b\K~';
```

with the same replacement string.

---

Pattern 1 details:

This pattern matches all characters until a $ (included). The easiest way to avoid quoted parts is to match all of them before a dollar and to remove all from the match result using `\K`.
The A modifier (similar of `\G` at the start of the pattern) ensures that all matches are contiguous (without gaps).

```
~ # pattern delimiter
[^"'$]*+ #"# all characters except quotes and dollars
(?: # quoted parts
    "[^"]*" [^'"$]*  
  |
    '[^']*' [^"'$]*  
)*+
\$
\b  # no need to write `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` and to capture it
    # after a literal "$" a word boundary suffices.
\K  # KEEP: characters before this token are removed from the match result
~A  # ANCHORED: force the matches to be contiguous from the start 
    # of the string until the last match. If one position fails, no
    # more match are possible
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
$str = '{{ $here $their "$literal" }}';
$result = preg_replace('/(\$.*?)\s(\$.*?)/i', '$this->$1 $this->$2', $str);
```

---

**DEMO**
http://ideone.com/DO45Se